# Structured streaming multiple watermarks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.3.0 if that matters.

According to the Structured Streaming documentation, it handles [late data using watermarks](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking). It also mentions that streaming deduplication is also achieved by using watermarking to keep a limit on how much of [enter link description here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication) an intermediate state is stored.

So, my question is if these watermarks can have different values or is the watermark specified only once? I ask this because I will be deduplicating values after aggregation so the tolerance for handling late data is different.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Policy for handling multiple watermarks](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#policy-for-handling-multiple-watermarks):

> A streaming query can have multiple input streams that are unioned or joined together. Each of the input streams can have a different threshold of late data that needs to be tolerated for stateful operations. You specify these thresholds using withWatermarks("eventTime", delay) on each of the input streams.
>
> While executing the query, Structured Streaming individually tracks the maximum event time seen in each input stream, calculates watermarks based on the corresponding delay, and chooses a single global watermark with them to be used for stateful operations. By default, the minimum is chosen as the global watermark because it ensures that no data is accidentally dropped as too late if one of the streams falls behind the others (for example, one of the streams stop receiving data due to upstream failures). In other words, the global watermark will safely move at the pace of the slowest stream and the query output will be delayed accordingly.
>
> Since Spark 2.4, you can set the multiple watermark policy to choose the maximum value as the global watermark by setting the SQL configuration spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy to max (default is min).

In fact, this also applies to any watermark-sensitive operator.

Comment: Thanks, Jacek for your help. But what I am trying to understand is that when we have ONLY ONE stream, but several watermark-sensitive operators to apply, like drop duplicates, event-time timeout in case of arbitrary stateful processing, is watermark and the delay threshold specified only once which means it can't vary between these operators? So, if we drop duplicates which are older than 20 minutes  we can't have an even-time timeout which is 30 minutes, right?

Comment: That's easy to verify yourself! :) Use `explain` on the streaming dataset and you'll know the answer since there'll be just one...ok...won't disclose it and leave it for you to let us know what you found out yourself :)